# Does increase in pressure increases boiling point of flowing liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]
From Bernoulli's equation
When a Liquid flows from smaller cross section area to larger cross section area velocity decreases and pressure increases

From this point i have a doubt i am not from mechanical stream..!!

does this increase in pressure increases boiling point of liquid??

Comment: @thunderbolt That only applies if you are trying to boil the vapour _into the atmosphere_.  Inside this pipe, you could get the water to a higher temperature than 100°C and it wouldn't boil _until exposed_ to atmospheric pressure; boiling point depends on temperature and pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the increase in pressure increases the boiling point of a liquid.

The opposite would also be true; that low pressure can lead to decreased boiling point of a liquid.  This concept is very well studied in dynamic liquid systems, especially turbo-machinery such as pumps.

When the pressure drops too much, it can lead to [cavitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation) where the pressure drops low enough to allow some of the liquid to form a bubble in the vapour phase.  When this collapses, it can cause serious damage to machinery, and thus is a fairly well studied concept.